# Python3 - getting the sum of a particular row from all the files

Tags: python, file

I have many files in my directory of the below format:

```
name,sex,count
xyz,M,231
abc,F,654
...
```

i am trying to get the sum of count(3rd coloumn) for all files and store them in a list.

```
total = []
result = 0
for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file = open(direc + '/' + filename, 'r')
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            if sex == 'F':
                result += int(count)
                total.append(result)
```

Any tips as to why my code doesn't work?

trying to get:

```
[sum(file1), sum(file2)...]
```

EDIT:

INPUT :

```
file1:
xyz,M,231
abc,F,654

file2:
wee,M,231
pol,F,654
bgt,M,434
der,F,543

file3:
wer,F,432
uio,M,124
poy,F,783
```

Comment: _What_ does not work?

Comment: the list 'total' is not giving me sum of counts for all the files.

Comment: As a point of terminology: The way you asked your question has confused a lot of people because the word *row* means a horizontal line of data. So the third row of your example (including the header) is `abc,F,654`. It's not completely clear whether you really mean the third row or the third *column*. The third column in your example is `count,231,654`.

Comment: @JohnY yes im sorry. it was a typo. i meant 'column'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that works with the absolute bare minimum of modifications (that is, no style fixes were made):

```
total = []
for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    result = 0
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file = open(direc + '/' + filename, 'r')
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if sex == 'F':
                result += int(count)
    total.append(result)
```

The following had to be fixed:

1. The `result` variable was set to zero only once, not once per file, so each new file read kept adding to the previous file's total. By my understanding you are trying to add the result from each file to the `total` list, so I moved this line to make that variable have the correct result.
2. The line `name, sex, count = line.split(',')` is very fragile, whenever a line has a line without 2 commas in it (including the closing newlines), it would throw an error. I wrapped it in a try…except block that catches these errors and moves on to the next line when needed.
3. The `result` was appended to the `total` list on every line read, not per file.

If I misinterpreted your intentions and you just wanted to keep a running total in the `total` variable for reference, you only need to make modification #2.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always make sure you close file descriptors (it's not related to the problem, but it's a code style).
Also, you should use `os.path.join` to concatenate paths, because it's more portable (same comment).
Here is what it gives:

```
total = []
result = 0
for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(direc, filenameà, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip()
                name, sex, count = line.split(',')
                if sex == 'F':
                    result += int(count)
                    total.append(result)
```

Now, back to the problem: you don't select the third row, but all rows whose second column is F…

Here is how you would to it to get the third line:

```
total = []
result = 0
for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(direc + '/' + filename, 'r') as file:
            file.readline() # Read first line
            file.readline() # Read second line
            line file.readline() # Read third line
            line = line.strip()
            name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            result += int(count)
            total.append(result)
```

Comment: i have about thousand lines for each of my file. I just gave a sample of what i had to describe the format.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the header row of the text files so you aren't trying to parse "count" as an int.

Also, I'm guessing you only want result appended after the loop?

```
 total = []
 result = 0
 for filename in os.listdir(direc):
     if filename.endswith('.txt'):
         with open(direc + '/' + filename, 'r') as file:
             next(file)
             for line in file:
                 line = line.strip()
                 name, sex, count = line.split(',')
                 if sex == 'F':
                     result += int(count)
             total.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a few changes:

```
import glob
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for fname in glob.glob('/path/to/dir/*.txt'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                name, sex, count = line.split(',')
                if sex == 'F':
                    result[fname] += int(count)
            except ValueError:  # unpack error, integer conversion error
                print("ValueError with '{}', continuing".format(line))

print(result)
```

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a handy thing: It behaves like a normal dictionary, but if a key does not exist, it is being created with a default value, in this case a zero. Like this you can simply add to your value, and if a *total* is not yet existing it defaults to 0.

The `listdir` and `filename.endswith` structure can be avoided using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html), take a look if you like.

Then, integer-conversion and tuple-unpacking can be a troublesome business, especially when you have varying input. To prevent your script from breaking I'd recommend a `try...except` block.