# Python 3 - working with files

Tags: python, file

I have 100+ files in my directory each having 1000+ lines with the following format:

```
name,sex,number
```

for ex:

```
xyz,M,234
```

i need to get the sum of the number field for those files only where a particular name occurs at row 2 and sex is 'F'. But after checking the condition my code gives me the sum of number field for all the files in the directory. Here's my code:

```
total = []

for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    result = 0
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file = open(direc + '/' + filename, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            line = line.strip()
            name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            if 'xyz' == name and sex == 'F' and i == 2:
                for line in file:
                    line = line.strip()
                    name, sex, count = line.split(',')
                    if sex == 'F':
                        result += int(count)
            total.append(result)
```

What's wrong with my code. I just need sum of my 3rd column for sex = 'F' only those files where

```
'xyz' == name and sex == 'F' and i == 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python3 - getting the sum of a particular row from all the files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548094/python3-getting-the-sum-of-a-particular-row-from-all-the-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for starters, you're iterating on the same file twice and that will definitely mess up your results.

```
for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
```

and

```
            for line in file:
```

Part of the problem here is that a file object isn't a list where it's all in memory -- it's an iterator, and once you look at a line, it's gone. Just pull all of the lines into the memory with a list -- `lines = list(file)`, check if the second matches your conditions -- `'xyz', 'F' == lines[1].split(',')[:2]` -- and then act on the whole list if it's true.

For a single file:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = list(f)

if 'xyz', 'F' == lines[1].split(',')[:2]:
    result = 0
    for line in lines:
        name, sex, count = line.strip().split(',')
        if sex == "F":
            result += int(count)
```